# az devops login taking long time

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli

I am trying to login using ado.pat with the following commands:

```
1. cat ado.pat | az devops login 
2. cat ado.pat | az devops login --organization https://dev.azure.com/myorg
```

But I am seeing this message for both of them:

```
Failed to store PAT using keyring; falling back to file storage. 
You can clear the stored credential by running az DevOps logout. 
Refer aka.ms/azure-devops-cli-auth to know more on the sign in with PAT.
```

It takes about 10 minutes for the login after which I am able to run az CLI commands and create/clone/push repos. Any suggestions on what might be wrong? This doesn't seem to be a problem when my friend tries using his ado.pat. I have also tried re-creating the ado.pat and still no success.

Comment: Hi Kevin, I forgot to type https while writing the description. I did notice I was not using 2.16.0 version of az cli. Will update it and let you know if it worked

Comment: Feel free to let me know if it could work. If this issue still exists, I will still be here to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my test, I test the command `cat ado.pat | az devops login --organization https://dev.azure.com/orgname`  and it could work fine (Azure CLI version:2.16.0 and Azure Devops Extension: 0.18.0 ).

First of all, you need to add **https://** in your organization url.  If you don’t add this, my login will fail.

Then you could run the command(`az --version`)to check the Azure Cli and Azure Devops extension version.

You could Refer to this [Github Ticket](https://github.com/Azure/azure-devops-cli-extension/pull/880).

It seems that in the old version of azure devops extension, you will encounter the similar error message.

You could try to update the version to the latest or re-install the latest extension.

```
az extension update --name azure-devops
```

On the other hand, you could check if you have run other login commands before running az devops login(e.g. az login)

You can also try to run the `az devops logout` to clear the credentials. Then you could try to re-login.